# Is it possible to calculate covariance between 2 variables based on their individual covariance with a third variable

Tags: variables, covariance, variance

If one knows the covariance between A and B and the covariance between B and C, is it then possible to calculate the covariance between A and C?

Or what would you additionally need?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't.

If you know Cov(A, B) and Cov(B, C) then Cov(A, C) is *constrained*, but not uniquely defined.

The constraints can be found by asserting that the covariance matrix (of A, B, and C) is positive semi-definite: i.e. none of its eigenvalues can be negative.